# Is it possible to make title with line to export into pdf?

Tags: css, markdown

I'm writing a document in Typora and I need a paragraph break whitch is a line with text in the middle. The whole document should be exportable to pdf.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buVcp.png)

I currently tried this, but it doesn't work when exporting to pdf:

```css
h3 {
    color: #015573;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    position: relative;
    margin:0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
h3 span {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0 0.3em;
}
h3:before{
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #015573;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below code. It's working fine. You can export to pdf with no problems. I did not use the `background-color: white;` property because the background color is white by default of any exported pdf. BTW, if you are using a dark theme for Typora, you can specify that property. It won't affect the exported style in the pdf file.

```css
h3 {
    color: #015573;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
}
h3:before,
h3:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 2px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #015573;
}
h3:before {
    right: 0.5em;
    margin-left: -50%;
}
h3:after {
    left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: -50%;
}
```

```html
<h3>Heading</h3>
```

This is how exported pdf looks like:

[image: exported styled pdf]

Answer (score 0):

```css
.fancy {
 line-height: 0.5;
 text-align: center;
}

.fancy span {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}

.fancy span:before {
 right: 100%;
 margin-right: 15px;
}

.fancy span:before,
.fancy span:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 height: 5px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 top: 0;
 width: 600px;
}

.fancy span:after {
 left: 100%;
 margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<p class="fancy"><span>A fancy subtitle</span></p>
```

Comment: CSS-wise it works, but still when I export to .pdf fro typora it doesn't show the line :(

Comment: maybe because export pdf don't undrstnd the before and after of css, i'll try anothor solution ASAP